# Lucene, How multi-field search?

Tags: lucene

The user can search for a plurality of conditions, each condition is the relationship AND.

I hope 'buyers' and 'remark' Search results can meet the search criteria, convert sql statement is as follows: WHERE buyers LIKE '% xxxx%' AND remark LIKE '% xxxx%'

If I set BooleanClause.Occur.MUST two fields, will never find the results. But if I set one field to BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD, is can found, but do not meet the search criteria.

How can I get my Lucene(5.0) can be like WHERE buyers LIKE '% xxxx%' AND remark LIKE '%xxxx%' the same query?

My Code:

```
public List<T> query(int page, int size, String description, Date startDate, Date endDate, String buyers) {

    IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory.open(Paths.get(indexPath)));
    IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
    Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();

    BooleanQuery query = buildQuery(description, buyers, analyzer);
    Query arrivalDateQuery = NumericRangeQuery.newLongRange("arrivalDate", startDate.getTime(), endDate.getTime(), true, true);
    query.add(arrivalDateQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);

    // outout:+remark:tape +buyers:company +arrivalDate:[1356969600000 TO 1425916800000]
    logger.debug("queryString: " + query.toString());
}

private BooleanQuery buildQuery(String description, String buyers, Analyzer analyzer) {
    BooleanQuery query = new BooleanQuery();
    QueryBuilder builder = new QueryBuilder(analyzer);
    if (description.length() > 0) {
        Query descriptionQuery = builder.createBooleanQuery("remark", description);
        query.add(descriptionQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST); // error, not found
    }
    if (buyers.length() > 0) {
        Query buyersQuery = builder.createBooleanQuery("buyers", buyers);
        query.add(buyersQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST); // error, not found
    }
    return query;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me it should work...

1. What are the types of your fields? if they are not TextField, they will not be tokenized, this could be the problem.
2. If you put Occur.SHULD, what do the results look like? It would be easier to understand the problem If you'd show what the data looks like